# Rails4 rails-api test: undefined session_serializer when testing auth via headers token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, minitest, rails-api

I have written a small app in order to practice with minitest. The stack is versioned as
follows:

- Rails 4.1.4
- ruby 2.1.2p95
- devise 3.2.4
- devise_token_auth 0.1.25
- rails-api 0.2.1

The app has been generated from scratch as per rails-api instruction, and I can see
everything works as expected from the client side.

The difficutly I'm encountering is with controller's tests that have to deal with
authentication.

I took inspiration for this kind of test from:

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/test/controllers/demo_controller_test.rb

My test code is located at: http://pastebin.com/iPVk9Tzq

When I run the test suite I get back the following error:

```
PostsControllerTest#test_get_index_is_successful_if_logged_in:
NoMethodError: undefined method `session_serializer' for nil:NilClass
  test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:PostsControllerTest>'
```

I tried different searches over the net but I wasn't able to figure out how to solve
this issue.

I understand that the error happens because there's no session stored anywhere since the application is implemented as a stateless API.

Obviously if I comment out the "request.headers.merge! ..." line, the error disappear
and the test fails with a response of 401 (as it should when the user is not logged in).

Any help/suggestion is widely appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 4):

It turns out I simply forgot to include Devise::TestHelpers in my controller test class ...

Sorry :/